# Syntax: character literal contains multiple characters in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to define a string in Julia like I would in Python by doing the following:

```
'hello world'
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax: character literal contains multiple characters
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ none:1
```

Any suggestion to resolve this? I searched around for the error but nothing about Julia came up, only C# and other languages.

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Comment: See also [Julia Manual - Strings](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In languages like Python, it is possible to define a string with a single quote like this:

```py
'this is a valid python string'
```

However, in Julia, the single quote can only be used for an individual character. If you have more than one, you need to use double quotes:

```
"This is a valid Julia string"
#vs
'This is NOT a valid string'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is not complete without noting that in Julia you have also `"""`

```
help?> """

  """ is used to delimit string literals. Strings created by triple quotation marks 
  can contain " characters without escaping and are dedented to the level of the
  least-indented line. This is useful for defining strings within code
  that is indented.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> """Hello World!"""
  "Hello World!"

  julia> """Contains "quote" characters"""
  "Contains \"quote\" characters"

  julia> """
           Hello,
           world."""
  "Hello,\nworld."
```